# How can I traverse the parse tree generated by yacc?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, yacc

Suppose I have given a valid arithmetic expression to my yacc file. And now I want to show how the parse tree looks by traversing it in pre or post order. Is it possible to traverse the parse tree.Just a rookie in compiler design.

Comment: As [rici answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52326483/1256452), yacc does not build a parse tree. It does build (and destroy) a parse *stack* as it works; each shift is effectively a token-push, and each reduce is a series of pop operations (of however many tokens got pushed to get there). You need to build your own tree, preferably an AST rather than a raw token tree.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you build the tree yourself while you are parsing. Bison/yacc won't do that for you.

However, the reduce actions are effectively a depth-first pre-order walk, since the reductions happen bottom-up left-to-right. So you can get something very similar to a parse tree walk by putting your "visit" code in each reduction rule.

But you're really better off learning how to create ASTs.